# Have queue in refresh of indicies in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster of three elasticsearch nodes. One of them has HDD disk and the others have SSD. Unfortunately I have queue in refresh section and I cannot see any of the newly inserted documents. Is there any config to be able to solve this problem? I have set the refresh interval to 30 seconds and the queue size of refresh has become over 900 on each node. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large part of our queue was because of the HDD hard disk in one of our servers. Changing that could help us to have better performance and decrease the size of our refresh queues. The other important reason was that we were using single post index . By changing this to bulk insert, the problem completely solved.